# How do I create an hour column from this Time Occurred column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxtKa.png)

I need to just extract the hour from these integers. How can that be done?

I've been trying to use commands such as pd.DatetimeIndex but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is the format of the time? you take it as a timestamp?

Comment: First of all, please don't include images of text, code, or data.  Secondly, the time column in your image shows an integer value.  You can't use DatetimeIndex on an integer like that shown.  Please provide sufficient information to identify the basis of the time being recorded.  Also, provide an example of what your expected output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it seems difficult to understand what exactly you are looking for, but if the integer 2320 represents 23:20 and therefore the 23rd hour then you could do this:

```
df['Hour'] = df['Time Occured'].astype(str).map(lambda time: time[:len(time)-2]).astype(int)
```

1. cast type to string to access the length of the time
2. slice the string from beginning to the length of the string but remove the minutes.
3. cast back to integer